# strange behavior when calling external linux command

Tags: linux, mac-os-x, external-calls

My platform is Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.1.

When calling several external linux commands as the following:

```
Import["!source ~/.bash_profile && alias", "Text"]
```

the results are not what expected, which obviously didn't `source` my configuration file.
However, by replacing the `&&` with `;`, the following code

```
Import["!source ~/.bash_profile ; alias", "Text"]
```

works well.

The problem appears after upgrading to 10.0.2 and the former code worked well under previous versions on Yosemite.

I just want to confirm if this is a bug introduced in 10.0.2.

Comment: `Import["!ls -l && pwd", "Text"]` works for me with v.10.0.2 and OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: `pwd` does work with me. However, my case as in the question fails.

Comment: more specifically, `source` doesn't work.

Comment: ok, so I did the following test : 1/ created the file ~/test.txt containing the simple command `ll=ls -l` then 2/ in mma :`Import["!source ~/test.txt && alias", "Text"]` which returns properly returns `ll=ls -l`. Does it work for you ?

Comment: Hi @SquareOne, your method does work this time. But `source` my bash profile(i.e. `~/.bash_profile`) still fails. So weird... However, this used to work.